# Upgrading HAProxy 2.0.13 to 2.4.10 (Ubuntu 20.04) -- performance & issues?

Tags: haproxy, ubuntu-20.04

My company is currently using HAProxy 2.0.13 (from Ubuntu repository).

Since latest HAProxy (just released last month) is 2.5, we think HAProxy 2.0.13 is a bit "long in the tooth". Also, [(claimed) performance improvements of 2.1](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-2-1/) seems to be a 'nice to have'.

But due to the 'newness' of 2.5, it's not yet available in [HAProxy's ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Evbernat/+ppa-packages); but the [latest in the 2.4 line (i.e., 2.4.10)](https://www.haproxy.org/download/2.4/src/CHANGELOG) is available. So we figure we're going to upgrade to 2.4.10 instead.

My questions:

- Is it true that HAProxy 2.1 (and by extension 2.4.10) has better performance than 2.0?
- Is there any 'gotchas' I need to be aware of upgrading from 2.0 to 2.4?

Comment: my suggestion is, backup and create a snapshot and give a shot.

Comment: Capacity planning and load testing don't translate well to other hardware, use cases and environment. As djdomi said, give it a whirl and see how it goes for you. In any case, 2.0.13 is long overdue, the latest 2.0 is 2.0.26 so you should consider upgrading. If not to 2.4 then to the latest 2.0.